# Python re.match() over list and non-matches set to np.nan

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I wanted to use `re.match()` to check if every element in a list matches the format DigitFullstopDigitDigit (eg 2.00).

If an element does match the format, I want to attach that element to a new list. If the element doesn't match the format, I want to attach a NaN to my new list instead.

The problem is my code doesn't work; it sets all the elements to NaN.

Thanks for any help!

```
import re
import numpy as np 

lst = [2, 2.00, 2.2, 20000]
newlst = []

for l in lst:
    if re.match('^\d{1}(\.)\d{2}$', str(l)):
        newlst.append(l)
    else:
        newlst.append(np.nan) 

# Output
[nan, nan, nan, nan]
    
# Expected output
[nan, 2.00, nan, nan]
```

Comment: FYI, `str(2.00)` returns `'2.0'`

Comment: FYI, `'^\d{1}(\.)\d{2}$'` can be better written as `'^\d\.\d{2}$'` in this case. It matches strings like `#.##`. And the above comment is true, see [demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBVsFIz8CAq6AoM69Eo1jz/38A). Where did you get `lst = [2, 2.00, 2.2, 20000]` from? Typed in manually? Then make the strings form the start, `lst = ['2', '2.00', '2.2', '20000']`. See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##JYtLCsMwDET3PoUWBdlQjOuue5IkhZIPMcgfVC0SSs7uOmQ2bx7MlF3WnJ61hlgyC/CseINXox1zLIFmzfjup9/j0L01rfjjhkbRV9qqQ493QG@du3ipa8FBFQ5JdEewZAaCkOB8hQV4s/Ej46rJDKbWPw).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the

> str(l)

operation is simplifying your floating point number. From 2.0000000... to just '2.0'

And '2.0' does not match your pattern. One way you could fix this is by using this new pattern. Which will match 1 or more zeroes after the dot:

```
r'\d\.0+'
```

With the new pattern, your output will be as desired:

```
[nan, 2.0, nan, nan]
```